# Unexpected http/net response content length in Golang

Tags: http, go, get, content-length

I am making a HTTP Get request using the code below. I proxy it through Fiddler to analyse the request. The request seems to be being made correctly, with the expected response. However, the `resp.ContentLength` property of the response in GO is `-1` 
every time despite the fact that the response in Fiddler shows a positive integer value of `Content-Length: 1830`.

Why is the ContentLength not being picked up in GO?

**Go Code**

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "os"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://127.0.0.1:8888") // For Fiddler debugging
    resp,err := http.Get("http://www.google.com/robots.txt")
    if (err == nil) {
        if (resp.StatusCode == 200) {
            fmt.Println(resp.ContentLength) // Prints -1
        }
    }
}
```

**Resulting Request in Fiddler**

```
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

**Response Received in Fiddler**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 6907
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 13:53:00 GMT
Expires: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 13:53:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Mar 2018 18:00:00 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: check the answer down this question. it worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487632/19632867

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value -1 indicates that the length is unknown. (in most cases this indicates
chunked encoding).

Comment: That would make sense! Although I was under the impression that the server should return a 'chunked' header in the response if that is the case.

Comment: You can find more in the source https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my research.

There's a `DisableCompression` option in the `http.Transport` struct, which default to `false` (`http.Get` use this default option). With that option, go's internal package will forcing gzip compression by adding the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header in the request. After receiving the response, go's internal package will do the decompression job for us, so that we don't have to deal with the `gzip` chunk. They also delete the original `Content-Length` header because it's not correct anymore.

All of that "magic under the hood" behaviors give us what we see here, missing the `Content-Length` header.

Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transport.go#L182

Comment: I set the `DisableCompression` to `true`, still getting the content-length as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The content length change in func readTransfer https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transfer.go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).