# Disable decompression of HTTP body received from a server with incorrect headers

Tags: http, go, gzip

I have a simple, but infuriating issue: I'm trying to automatically download `.tar.gz` files from a web server, perform an MD5 checksum on them, and decompress them into a directory.

This is fairly easy to do, except for one problem: Some of the files have a `Content-Encoding: x-gzip` header set. This causes the `"net/http"` client to automatically decompress these files, making it impossible to verify their contents, and worse, making it difficult to unpack them (since you never quite know if you need to decompress them or not).

The server isn't mine, so I can't just fix the headers.

Is there any way to *completely disable* automatic decompression of response bodies with `"net/http"`? Failing that, is there anything else I can do to work around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `http.Transport.DisableCompression` to `true` ?

Comment: You are sure the response isn't double compressed?

Comment: @vedhavyas Somehow, despite digging around in the docs for far too long, I missed that field. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the reponse is not decompressed: https://play.golang.org/p/bxSQUlOMj5E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a custom HTTP transport:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    DisableCompression: true,
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

This `client` will not decompress *any* of the responses, so you're free to handle that yourself